# Extjs textfield binding

Tags: extjs, data-binding, textfield

I am trying to find the best way to bind items to a textfield in my extjs project. I downloaded the data into a store with one record in the controller. How would I bind to this textfield from the one record?  I would preferably bind in the view, not in the controller

Comment: Hi Stephen,
Can you please post and elaborate, what you have done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read [this guide](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/guides/application_architecture/view_models_data_binding.html) to understand better what binding is

The best solution for you is bind the record on the viewmodel of the view, so:

```
textfield.setBind({
  value:'{myRec.valueToRefer}'
})
viewmodel.set('myRec',record.getData());
```

If you want, you can also use a form to handle this, using `form.loadRecord` and giving to the textfield a name..

A tip:
set inside the viewmodel a value to null:

```
data:{
 myRec:null
}
```

Set your record in the viewmodel after setting the bind to the textfield.

Other tip:
If you can, avoid using setBind and prefer to set the binding directly on textfield creation:

//WILL WORK BUT YOU CAN AVOID IT

```
textfield.setBind({
      value:'{myRec.valueToBind}'
     })
```

//YES

```
var textfield=Ext.create({
 xtype:'textfield',
 bind:{
  value:'{myRec.valueToBind}'
 }
});
```

[Refer to Sencha documentation also](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/)

Comment: thanks... that got it working.  I read through the guide and it all was about a view model.  I created a view model with a variable for form data, then in the controller I used the one record in the store to populate formdata... then binded to it.  thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`bind`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-bind) config to bind the data or any other `config` for ExtJS `component`.

> **Bind** setting this config option adds or removes data bindings for other configs.

For example, to `bind` the title config:

```
var panel = Ext.create({
     xtype: 'panel',
     bind: {
         title: 'Hello {user.name}'
     }
});
```

To dynamically `add` bindings:

```
panel.setBind({
     title: 'Greetings {user.name}!'
});
```

To `remove` bindings:

```
panel.setBind({
     title: null
});
```

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2fak)**, I have created a demo for biding. I hope this will help/guide you to achieve you requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        //defining Store
        Ext.define('Store', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

            alias: 'store.gridstore',

            autoLoad: true,

            fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],

            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',

                url: 'data1.json',

                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: ''
                }
            }
        });

        //defining view model
        Ext.define('MyViewModel', {

            extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',

            alias: 'viewmodel.myvm',

            data: {
                formdata: null
            },

            stores: {
                gridstore: {
                    type: 'gridstore'
                }
            }
        });

        //Controller
        Ext.define('MyViewController', {
            extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
            alias: 'controller.myview',

            onGridItemClick: function (grid, record) {
                //Bind the form data for CLICKED record
                this.getViewModel().set('formdata', record)
            }
        });

        //creating panel with GRID and FORM
        Ext.create({

            xtype: 'panel',

            controller: 'myview',

            title: 'Binding Example',

            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

            viewModel: {
                type: 'myvm'
            },

            layout: 'vbox',

            items: [{
                xtype: 'grid',

                flex: 1,

                width: '100%',

                bind: '{gridstore}',

                columns: [{
                    text: 'Name',
                    dataIndex: 'name'
                }, {
                    text: 'Email',
                    dataIndex: 'email',
                    flex: 1
                }, {
                    text: 'Phone',
                    dataIndex: 'phone'
                }],

                listeners: {
                    itemclick: 'onGridItemClick'
                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'form',

                flex: 1,

                width: '100%',

                defaults: {
                    anchor: '100%'
                },

                title: 'Bind this form on Grid item Click',

                bodyPadding:15,

                margin: '20 0 0 0',

                // The fields
                defaultType: 'textfield',

                items: [{
                    fieldLabel: 'Name',
                    name: 'first',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    bind: '{formdata.name}'
                }, {
                    fieldLabel: 'Email',
                    name: 'email',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    bind: '{formdata.email}'
                }, {
                    fieldLabel: 'Phone',
                    name: 'phone',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    bind: '{formdata.phone}'
                }]
            }]
        });
    }
});
```